# Elastic search create custom analyzer using Python client HTTP 400 issue

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a custom analyzer with elastic search python client. I'm referring to this article in elastic search documentation.
[elastic docs article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html)

When I send a PUT request with the following JSON settings it sends 200 Success.

```json
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": { 
          "char_filter": [
            "emoticons"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "punctuation",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "punctuation": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "[ .,!?]"
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "emoticons": { 
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            ":) => _happy_",
            ":( => _sad_"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": { 
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue comes when I try to do the same with the python client. Here's how I am using it.

`settings.py` to define settings

```py
settings = {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": { 
          "char_filter": [
            "emoticons"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "punctuation",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "punctuation": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "[ .,!?]"
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "emoticons": { 
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            ":) => _happy_",
            ":( => _sad_"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": { 
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`create-index helper method`

```py
es_connection.create_index(index_name="test", mapping=mapping, settings=settings)
```

`es-client call`

```py
def create_index(self, index_name: str, mapping: Dict, settings) -> None:
        """
        Create an ES index.
        :param index_name: Name of the index.
        :param mapping: Mapping of the index
        """
        logging.info(f"Creating index {index_name} with the following schema: {json.dumps(mapping, indent=2)}")
        self.es_client.indices.create(index=index_name, ignore=400, mappings=mapping, settings=settings)
```

I get the following error from logs

```json
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.analyzer.my_custom_analyzer.char_filter] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.analyzer.my_custom_analyzer.char_filter] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings","suppressed":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.analyzer.my_custom_analyzer.filter] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.analyzer.my_custom_analyzer.tokenizer] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.char_filter.emoticons.mappings] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.char_filter.emoticons.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.filter.english_stop.stopwords] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.filter.english_stop.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.tokenizer.punctuation.pattern] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.tokenizer.punctuation.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}]},"status":400}
```

Any idea what causes this issue ??? Related to ignore 400 ???? Thanks in advance.

PS - I'm using `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.1` and python elasticsearch client 7.15.1

Comment: Which Python client/library are you using?

Comment: @Val https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch/

Comment: Also I'm using docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.1 and python elasticsearch client 7.15.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to remove the `settings` section at the top because it's [added automatically by the client code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/main/elasticsearch/_sync/client/indices.py#L432):

```
settings = {
  "settings": {          <--- remove this line
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
```